# ANDROID App is not compatible with any devices

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to publish a live wallpaper however the store/developers console keeps saying my app is not compatible with any devices.

I am not sure what is wrong. Below is my manifest. I believe This should support all screen sizes so I dont think that is it. I am not sure what else it could be.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="go.me.pinglivewallpaper"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.3" >
    <supports-screens
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="com.go.wallpaper"
        android:required="true" >
    </uses-feature>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/a"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <service
            android:name="wallpaper"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="Ping Wallpaper "
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@layout/mywallpaper" >
            </meta-data>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Change targetSdkVersion to 19. 20 is for wearables.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try deleting:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="com.go.wallpaper"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>
```

as [there is no such feature in the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).

Answer (score 1):

I removed the below and changed to SDK version 19.

Thank you.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="com.go.wallpaper"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>
```